# SharePoint - How to Group Search Results Using Default Display Templates

Tags: sharepoint, display-templates

Is there documentation on how to create groups for search results, preferably using managed properties?  All that I was able to find on it is using query rules, result blocks, or this great tutorial: http://www.eliostruyf.com/grouping-search-results-with-display-templates-for-the-cswp/, **but** it uses completely custom templates while I'm using modified versions of the default control, item, and group display templates and I really want to retain many of their features and just add what I need instead.

I want to organize the results by site title.  I'm hoping to use each item's `ParentLink` managed property to get the Parent URL or Parent Web and from there, get the title.  The search is collecting different items from all the site collections in the farm so that's why I want to organize it this way.  How can I at least make groups?  Where would this be placed within the control, item, and group templates?